# Installing highcharter R library - working directory error

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the R highcharter library on a new computer.

When I do the following

```
install.packages(highcharter)
library(highcharter)
```

and run

```
 hc<-highchart() %>% 
     hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
     hc_title(text = "A highcharter chart") %>% 
     hc_xAxis(categories = 2012:2016) %>% 
     hc_add_series(data = c(3900,  4200,  5700,  8500, 11900), name = "Downloads")
 hc
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in setwd(dir) : cannot change working directory
```

I cannot understand why am I getting such error related with directories.

Can someone help me please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Works for me. With the small difference that I used `install.packages("highcharter")` (notice the quotes). What OS and version of R are you using? Is the install successful with no errors?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I'm using R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) and OS Windows 10 64bits

Comment: I cannot reproduce with the same R and OS.

Comment: Please start a new clean R session (make sure there are no workspaces loaded when powering up R), load the library and run the chunk of code in this question. If the problem persists there may be something wrong with your setup and not the code.